# Notice: Undefined offset: 234 in ... Modifier/Eav.php on line 614

Tags: magento2

since today I can't edit products as I see the error attached:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi any changes you did in the database directly in the EAV attribute table? if not then try to disable your custom extensions and see if it is working or not.

Comment: I have solved doing upgrade, content deploy...

Comment: Great Thanks for your update :)